# Using admin site in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with two date fields, for submitted and published and a boolean field for approved.

```
class BlogModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    article = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField('date submitted')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return 'approved, ' + str(self.approved) + ' article, ' + self.article
```

I have included this model in admin.py. Admin can approve the article, but is it possible to have the pub_date be the current time when the article is approved in admin?

***UPDATE*** These models work for me in forms.py as suggested by Raja Simon

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogModel
        fields = '__all__'
        # fields = ('id', 'title', 'article')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        m = super(BlogForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # do custom stuff
        m.pub_date = timezone.now()
        if commit:
            m.save()
        return m
```

and admin.py

```
class BlogModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogForm
    fields = ('title', 'article', 'pub_date', 'submitted_date', 'author', 'approved')
    # fields = '__all__' won't work here, each field needs to be added individually as above
    pass
admin.site.register(BlogModel, BlogModelAdmin)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override form save in admin

```
class BlogModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogModelForm
    pass
admin.site.register(BlogModel, BlogModelAdmin)
```

And in `forms`

```
class BlogModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        m = super(BlogModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # do custom stuff
        m.pub_date = timezone.now()
        if commit:
            m.save()
        return m
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible by over riding the save_model method in your admin

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.approved:
        obj.pub_date =  timezone.now()
```

This is probably superior to overriding the save method in the model itself.